# ITunes and Catalina

Tags: macos, itunes, catalina

If I upgrade to Catalina will I still be able to import songs? If there is no iTunes were are the MP3 files going? Can I still bring music from my mac to use my iPods?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the new Music application has taken on the music-related roles of iTunes. You can sync music to an iPod Touch from the Music application, but for an iPod Classic I think you’ll need to use Finder, and you may need to reformat it — see [this thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/synching-clickwheel-ipods-with-catalina-request-for-confirmation.2203387/).